# How can I use the SELECT CONVERT command without splitting my data into multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a fairly simple query, mostly just returning relevant data for a report.  One field required me to modify the data (Taking `EMPLOYEE`, converting to `varchar`, and adding a string), which required a `SELECT CONVERT` line.  My problem is that this then breaks my results into two tables, when I wanted the converted data to simply fall into the results.  I know this is tied to my second `SELECT (SELECT CONVERT)`, but I don't know how to achieve my goal, which is one table that includes the converted data.[SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jccz2.png)

---

```
SELECT ID=''
      ,[LAST_NAME] AS [LNAME]
      ,[FIRST_NAME] AS [FNAME]      
      ,[MIDDLE_NAME] AS [MNAME]
      ,[EMPLOYEE] AS [PERSON_NO] 
     FROM [LSLMDB].[ls_apps].[EMPLOYEE]
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20),EMPLOYEE)+'xxxxx.org' AS [USERNAME]
      ,HOME_COMPANY='xxx'
      ,[DATE_HIRED] AS [HIRED_ON]
      ,[EMPLOYEE] AS [EMAIL]
      ,JOB_TYPE= ''
      ,[HM_ACCT_UNIT] AS [COMPANY]
FROM [LSLMDB].[ls_apps].[EMPLOYEE]
```

---

Comment: Please put the relevant code in the question itself, not as an image.

Comment: I am unsure what the issue is. If your issue is that you don't want two separate select statements, then just combine them?

Comment: How would I complete the CONVERT without the second SELECT?  I actually need them to fall in the order I have listed, as that is the format for the application the end user will upload the resulting file into.  I'm trying to avoid script-based manipulation.

Comment: Gusti, thanks.... This was the first time I had used the CONVERT, and all the examples I looked at said it had to be a SELECT CONVERT... Obviously my SQL knowledge is extremely shallow and I should have done some more searching. That easy fix got me up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your query to this :

```
SELECT ID=''
  ,[LAST_NAME] AS [LNAME]
  ,[FIRST_NAME] AS [FNAME]      
  ,[MIDDLE_NAME] AS [MNAME]
  ,[EMPLOYEE] AS [PERSON_NO] 
  ,CONVERT(varchar(20),EMPLOYEE)+'xxxxx.org' AS [USERNAME]
  ,HOME_COMPANY='xxx'
  ,[DATE_HIRED] AS [HIRED_ON]
  ,[EMPLOYEE] AS [EMAIL]
  ,JOB_TYPE= ''
  ,[HM_ACCT_UNIT] AS [COMPANY]
FROM [LSLMDB].[ls_apps].[EMPLOYEE]
```